# How to create a Objective-c Prefix.pch header file for swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Right now I have a swift project, and I add some objective-c files into the project. But the objective-c files have a prefix header file so I don't have to import every one of them to each objective-c files. I know how to do it in objective-c project. But right now I am in swift project. So how to do it?

Comment: @ArdaKeskiner I didn't mean bridging header. I mean prefix.pch file